# Displaying Google Spreadsheet Data with json2html

Tags: html, json

I'm interested in using json2html to display Google spreadsheet data
on a website.

Specifically, to display contents of this feed on a page:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Am0zfph_qjJMdEJrOTQxQ3A1N2xneU9ac003Szd2MVE/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script

Under the "Examples" tab on the json2html website, there's a sample for displaying the NHL's feed. This is pretty much what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm not entirely sure which json tag would go where in the script markup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO, You need to make your question more specific, please read the [FAQ]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to display the data (and which data). For now I'm assuming that you want to display the cell entries.  Here is something to get you started (note you can also use the jquery plugin with the same transform)

```
    var transform = 
        {"tag": "li", "children": [
            {"tag":"p", "html":"${content.$t}"},    
        ]};

    var data = json2html.transform(gData.feed.entry,transform);

    document.write('<ul>'+ data + '<ul>');
```

Comment: oh sorry forgot to add that the gData = json from the resulting link you posted

Comment: also this might help as well to view the json output http://visualizer.json2html.com/

Comment: Hm, still not showing up. Would it have to do with the "callback function" section

Comment: well you need to make sure you pull the json out of the callback function .. best to first create a static file with the json from the callback embedded within it.  Then you can wrap up the above code in the callback function to get it working for any dataset